# Store Debug Information error

Tags: magento-1.9, debug, captcha

I have been getting this Error via e-mail with the subject **"Store Debug Information"**, And I can't figure out whats causing it.  I know it has something to do with **Captcha**!

How do you read this error? How can it be fixed?

> URL: https://MyDomainDOTcom:443/captcha/refresh/
>   IP Address: 1.1.1.1
>   Time: 2016-05-29 14:28:36 GMT 
>   Error:
>   formId is mandatory
>   Trace:
>   `#0 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model    /Config.php(1354): Mage_Captcha_Model_Zend->__construct(Array)`
>   `#1 /home/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(463):     Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('captcha/zend', Array)`
>   `#2 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Helper/Data.php(72): Mage::getModel('captcha/zend', Array)`
>   `#3 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/RefreshController.php(45): Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data->getCaptcha(NULL)`
>   `#4 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Captcha_RefreshController->indexAction()`
>   `#5 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')`
>   `#6 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))`
>   `#7 /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()`
>   `#8 /home/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)`
>   `#9 /home/public_html/magento/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')`
>   `#10 {main}`

Answer (score 1):

The formId is missing from the captcha URL you set in your phtml file. Not sure whether you have included the captch in a custom form. In default forms(customer register, forgot password, login etc), this wont happen unless you override and modified it.

Let me explain how it works in default magento:

In app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/RefreshController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $formId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('formId');
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock($captchaModel->getBlockName())->setFormId($formId)->setIsAjax(true)->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode(array('imgSrc' => $captchaModel->getImgSrc())));
    $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
}
```

This method need "formId" to be posted when requesting to regenerate the captcha. The formId can be set in the layout xml as below (refer app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml):

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="customer_form_login">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>user_login</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

The formId should be unique for each action. This helps to validate the captcha.

In your phtml, you need to include the formId as below (refer app/design/frontend/base/default/template/captcha/zend.phtml):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $('<?php echo $this->getFormId() ?>').captcha = new Captcha('<?php echo $this->getRefreshUrl() ?>', '<?php echo $this->getFormId() ?>');
//]]></script>
```

on a different note:

If you are note sure how the emails are reaching your inbox, see below:

In errors/local.xml you can control whether your errors should be printed or emailed.

```
<config>
    <report>
        <action>email/print</action>
        <subject>Store Debug Information</subject>
        <email_address>example@example.com</email_address>
        <trash>leave</trash>
    </report>
</config>
```

Comment: @user2774042 Any updates? Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but In case others come across this, I had this issue come up today too. After investigating, I came across this article (https://www.bemaged.com/en/blog/magento-captcha-error-formid-is-mandatory/) which suggests a bot finding its way to the captcha. I've poppped /captcha/ in my robots.txt.
You can actually replicate the error by visiting your website's domain with captcha/refresh/ at the end. You should get an error page and an identical error message.
I investigated the IP involved in the error, and I am sure it was not human interaction that caused it. I think if you check your IP logs and cross reference server visitor logs / browser strings and IP reputation, you will find it's not a regular customer/browser and you can probably safely ignore it. If you like, pop a robots.txt rule in for the good obedient bots:

Disallow: /captcha/

If this happens a lot for you and it's definately not your website visitors (I have not tested this, I'm observing my site), follow this suggestion (http://www.pkdavies.co.uk/131-magento-formid-is-mandatory-on-captcha-refresh.html) but don't edit core files! Create a copy of the file "app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/RefreshController.php" in ""app/code/**local**/Mage/Captcha/controllers/RefreshController.php" and take it from there. What he suggests is add a check to see if the form ID exists, after line 44 (or there abouts), add:

```
if (empty($formId)) return false;
```

This is the first time I've come across this. I'd welcome any comments/edits/updates to this answer.